# Ignore outliers for stripplot

Tags: matplotlib, visualization, seaborn

I am trying to create a boxplot with jitter using the `boxplot` and `stripplot` in `seaborn`. Unfortunately my data has some outliers so I decide to exclude them in the final plot.

For the boxplot, it's easy to use `showfliers=False` argument to ignore the outliers. However stripplot does not have the similar argument. Since my dataset has outliers with extreme values, the y-axis is over-stretched, making it difficult to see the boxes.

Sample code:

```
import seaborn as sns
tips = sns.load_dataset("tips")
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax = sns.boxplot(x="day", y="total_bill", data=tips, showfliers=False)
ax = sns.stripplot(x="day", y="total_bill", data=tips)
fig.show()
```

[image]

Would it be easier just to filter out the outliers in the original dataframe before plotting?

Comment: Yes, that is one way but outliers can be useful to analyze in some cases. What you can actually do is change the orientation of the plot and get a wider plot instead of taller

Answer (score 4):

This should solve the problem:
You can get the limits for y_axis after creating the boxplot and then use that to set the ylim of the figure.

```
import seaborn as sns
tips = sns.load_dataset("tips")
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax = sns.boxplot(x="day", y="total_bill", data=tips, showfliers=False)
ylims=ax.get_ylim()
ax = sns.stripplot(x="day", y="total_bill", data=tips)
ax.set(ylim=ylims)
fig.show()
```